# Scrollorama elements "on pin"

Tags: jquery-plugins, scroll

I am using Scrollorama for scroll animations and I am having vertical spacing issues with the element beneath the pinned container

http://patrick.tbfdev.com/about-tahiti.php

As you scroll down you will notice that once the first container pins, the element beneath (blue sky image) descends down the page. This is NOT the desired behavior. The desired behavior is for the element beneath pinned object to remain coupled.

Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var controller = $.superscrollorama({
    triggerAtCenter: false,
    playoutAnimations: true
});


// set duration, in pixels scrolled, for pinned element
var pinDur = 900;
// create animation timeline for pinned element
var pinAnimations = new TimelineLite();


    pinAnimations
        .append([
            TweenMax.to($('#slide-a1'), 1.5, {css:{right:'+=2200px', ease:Bounce.easeOut}, delay:0.2}),
            TweenMax.to($('#slide-a2'), 1.2, {css:{right:'+=2400px', ease:Bounce.easeOut}, delay:0}),
            TweenMax.to($('#slide-a3'), 1.3, {css:{right:'+=3800px', ease:Bounce.easeOut}, delay:.2}),
            TweenMax.to($('#slide-a4'), 1.5, {css:{right:'+=5400px', ease:Bounce.easeOut}, delay:.4}),
            TweenMax.to($('#slide-a5'), 1.6, {css:{right:'+=6250px', ease:Bounce.easeOut}, delay:.6})
            ]
        , -1)
        .append([
            TweenMax.to($('#info-a1'), 1.2, {css:{right:'+=2200px', ease:Bounce.easeOut}, delay:0.1}),
            TweenMax.to($('#info-a2'), 1.1, {css:{right:'+=2400px', ease:Bounce.easeOut}, delay:0.5}),
            TweenMax.to($('#info-a3'), 1.0, {css:{right:'+=2800px', ease:Bounce.easeOut}, delay:1.1}),
            TweenMax.to($('#info-a4'), 1.3, {css:{right:'+=2400px', ease:Bounce.easeOut}, delay:1.4})

            ]
        , -2.4)

// pin element, use onPin and onUnpin to adjust the height of the element
    controller.pin($('#pin1'), pinDur, {
        anim:pinAnimations, 
        onPin: function() {
            $('#pin1').css('height','100%');
        }, 
        onUnpin: function() {
            $('#pin1').css('height','808px');
        }
    });
```